# svchost connects to localhost port 8002

Tags: svchost

I'm investigating why, on some Windows computer, `svchost` is connecting to localhost port 8002 every 4 minutes and 4 seconds, doing a HEAD request on `/Content/68/4CF523BF32D0464DF7DBF6FFAE434618CFDC3068.exe`, and hanging up before an answer is provided. It seems quite suspicious to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was the "Oracle Enterprise Manager Ops Center", which is referenced in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27363_01/doc.121/e52290.pdf and mentions the following traffic:

- *from* Agent Controller
- *to*, Proxy Controller
- *Port* 8002
- *what* Agent Controllers download updates

so it's only a virus in the sense that it's [1] auto-updating tooling and [2] made by Oracle but it is likely not suspicious in the way I originally feared.